# C# Bitshift & Bitwise operation

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am trying to find the faster approach for the following problem.

I have 2 int arrays representing bits, here an example of an 8 positions one

```
int[] intArray1 = new[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
int[] intArray2 = new[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1};
```

The number of bits in the arrays could be 8, 32, 64 and 64+

So I should be able to create an algorithm that handles any kind of input, shifts bits for each and applies logical operations between both arrays  in the faster way possible.

After a bit of research, I thought of casting the int array to a bool array and create a **BitArray** using the bool array, because **BitArray** has a constructor that supports bools as bits and it has built-in bit-wise operations.

```
bool[] boolArray = intArray.Select(s => s.Equals(1)).ToArray();
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(boolArray);
```

However it does not support built-in bit-shifting, it needs to be done iterating, loosing the whole performance point that I am trying to achieve.

I could use int32 and int64 but that solution will not work for sizes larger than 64 bits.

Kind Regards

Comment: BitArray is fairly clunky.  For a good reason, this isn't easy to make efficient on the processor either.  It drops the ball beyond 64 bits and only assembly code can make it do better, the kind that can't be generated by MSIL.  Just google "c# bitarray shift" for hits, doubtful they'll look much different from what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a `BigInteger`?

You can use this method to convert a `string` to a `BigInteger`:

```
public static BigInteger BinToDec(string value)
{
    // BigInteger can be found in the System.Numerics dll
    BigInteger res = 0;

    // I'm totally skipping error handling here
    foreach(char c in value)
    {
        res <<= 1;
        res += c == '1' ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Or if you want to stick with your `int` array and convert that to a `BigInteger`:

```
public static BigInteger BitArrayToBigDecimal(int[] bitIntArr) {
    // BigInteger can be found in the System.Numerics dll
    BigInteger res = 0;

    // I'm totally skipping error handling here
    foreach(int i in bitIntArr) {
        res <<= 1;
        res += i == 1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return res;
}
```

You can bit shift them, too.  Like this:

```
var foo = BinToDec("11101101");

BigInteger fooShifted = foo >> 4;

var bar = BitArrayToBigDecimal(new[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1});

BigInteger barShifted = bar >> 4;
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: it needs to handle lager inputs than 64, biginteger is 64bits

Comment: @MrVoid A `BigInteger` grows dynamically.  From the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx): A `BigInteger` "Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer."  Theoretically it could be infinitely large, but it is just limited by the .NET object size (about 2GB.)